# Sharing digital content - Delivering video to a selected device (Google) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, google, us20130227076a1

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON delivering video to a user devices** - This application from [Google](http://www.google.com) seeks to patent the idea of...offering a list of registered devices to a user so a video can be transferred to the selected device and the user can watch it! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 2/27/2012** that discusses:

> - Transferring video (or other content) to selected devices from among a list of devices **previously registered** to a user

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - reformatting or transcoding the content into a format that is compatible with the selected device.

**TITLE: Delivering videos to user-selected device**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A method for delivering video to a user.  User selects among a list of registered devices.  Video is transferred to the selected device so user can view it.

- **Publication Number**: [US20130227076 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130227076?dq=US20130227076A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/406,407
- **Assignee**: Google Inc.
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 2/27/2012
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 2/25/2014
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130227076)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method comprising:
>
> 1. receiving at a content delivery system, from a content provider system, a request, associated with a user accessing the content provider system, to transfer a video stored on a content source system to a viewing device of the user;
> 2. identifying a plurality of viewing devices registered to the user;
> 3. providing, to the user, a list of the user's registered viewing devices;
> 4. receiving, from the user, a selection of one of the user's viewing devices; and
> 5. transferring the video from the content source system to the selected viewing device, whereby the user is able to subsequently view the content item on the selected viewing device.

In English this means:

> A method of content deliver, comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving request to transfer a video from a content store to a device
> 2. Identifying multiple viewing devices associated with user
> 3. Providing user a list of registered viewing devices
> 4. User selects a viewing device
> 5. Transferring video from content source to the selected viewing device so user can view it.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 2/27/2012

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming reformatting or transcoding the content to be compatible with selected device

---

**"Delivering user's video to a selected device from a list of registered devices from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: This sounds a little like AirPlay, but I'm not sure if connecting to the same network counts as "previously registered" to the user...

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has always given you the choice of which compatible device to send stuff too. If I buy a movie, it can be sent to one of 2 computers or a tablet, if it's a book, I can choose to have it sent to either a physical kindle, or a kindle app I have installed on my phone, if it's an android app, I can choose to have it sent to my phone, or the development emulator I have set up. I first remember the choice of devices with Amazon Unbox, which according to [a press release](http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=97664&p=irol-newsArticle&ID=971365&highlight=) was 2006.

I believe it met all 5 steps ca 2007.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple’s AirTunes protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay) (now know as AirPlay) was introduced in 2004. It lets users stream audio (and later video) from one device to another. An example is streaming songs from an iTunes library on a computer to an AirPort Express router. In the process, the [audio is converted](https://github.com/lperrin/node_airtunes#audio-streaming) from an iTunes-supported format (mp3, aac, wav, etc) to Apple Lossless.